# Binding and _.bindAll in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am confused about binding and the purpose of `_bind.All` in backbone.js. Below is a working code that creates a Modal view `#modal` and renders out comments fetched from the backend.

Firstly, in the code below, I have in the `initialize` function `_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderComments');`. Whether or not I do `_.bindAll()`, I have no problems calling `this.render()` and `this.renderComments()` inside `initialize()`. Are there any examples of when `_.bindAll()` will help us and when it will not?

```
ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#modal'),

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderComments');
        this.render();
        this.renderComments();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).fadeIn('fast').append( this.template( this.model.toJSON( this.model ) ) );
    },

    renderComments: function() {
        this.commentList = new CommentCollection();
        var self = this;
        this.commentList.fetch({
            data: { post_id: this.model.id},
            processData: true,
            success: function() {
                self.commentListView = new CommentListView({ collection: self.commentList });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And

```
CommentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.modal_comments',

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each( function(comment, index) {
            $(self.el).append( new CommentListItemView({ model: comment }).render().el );
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Secondly, I am confused about prepending `this.` to something. For example in `renderComments`, why cant I use:

```
var commentList = new CommentCollection();
var self = this;
commentList.fetch({.... });
```

For the line `this.commentList = new CommentCollection();`, other than instantiating the class `CommentCollection()`, does it make `commentList` a child of `ModalView`?

Additionally, is it necessary to have `var self = this;` and use `self.commentListView` later in the callback function? Can binding be used so  I can access `this.commentListView`, or is using `var self = this` the conventional way of doing things?

Finally, should `self.commentListView = new CommentListView({ collection: self.commentList });` in the success function of `renderComments` be moved to `CommentListView`'s initialize method instead and be binded to `this.collection.on('reset');` to prevent nesting too many functions? This will result in:

```
ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#modal'),

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderComments');
        this.render();
        this.renderComments();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).fadeIn('fast').append( this.template( this.model.toJSON( this.model ) ) );
    },

    renderComments: function() {
        this.commentList = new CommentCollection();
        this.commentListView = new CommentListView({ collection: this.commentList });
        this.commentList.fetch({
            data: { post_id: this.model.id},
            processData: true
        });
    }
});

CommentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.modal_comments',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each( function(comment, index) {
            $(self.el).append( new CommentListItemView({ model: comment }).render().el );
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

phew--long question(s) ;)

1) I used to do `_.bindAll` in my initialize methods when I was first using backbone but I have since stopped.  It's not normally needed unless you're binding to events and then it's really helpful.  For example if you have:

```
events:
{
    'click': clickHandler
},
clickHandler: function(){
    //do cool stuff
}
```

then it's helpful to do `_.bindAll(this, 'clickHandler')` otherwise your `this` pointer won't be the view

2) If i understand your question: `commentList` becomes a property of your instance of `ModalView`.

3) using `var self = this;` is relatively common, but in many cases can be avoided because of overloads in Underscore.js (which is a dependency of backbone.js).  For instance, most of the collection functions (`map`, `each`, etc) take a context as the last parameter.  so instead of

```
var self = this;
_.map([1,2], function(item){
    self.sum = self.sum + item; 
});
```

you can do:

```
_.map([1,2], function(item){
    this.sum = this.sum + item; 
}, this);
```

if your case you could replace your `success` method with

```
success: _.bind(function() {
             this.commentListView = new CommentListView({ collection: this.commentList });
         }, this);
```

If you want more info on the somewhat confusing subject of this pointers, it's suggest the following excellent tutorial:  http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

4) Yes--I would move the rendering to the `reset`.  that way if something else causes a reset of the collection the view will pick it up.

Hope I answered all your questions.

Comment: This is not the case, at least in the most recent version of backbone anyway.  The 'events' object automatically calls the methods in the correct context (ie. the View)