# is `bindAll` outdated?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Of course i read manual, but as i see in classical example it doesn't really make a difference if i comment the line with binding. Are the methods bound now by default?

```
(function($){
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#TheList'), // el attaches to existing element
        events: {
            'click button#add': 'addItem'
        },

        initialize: function(){
            // _.bindAll(thathis, 'render', 'addItem'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

            this.counter = 0; // total number of items added thus far
            this.render();
        },

        render: function(){
            $(this.el).append('<button id="add">Add list item</button>');
            $(this.el).append('<ul></ul>');
            // console.log(this);
            // console.log(this.el);
        },

        addItem: function(){
            this.counter++;
            $('ul', this.el).append('<li>hello world'+this.counter+'</li>');
        }
    });

    var listView = new ListView();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513991/when-do-i-need-to-use-bindall-in-backbone-js?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402792/binding-and-bindall-in-backbone-js?rq=1

Comment: `_.bindAll` is rarely needed these days. Pretty everything that used to need it either uses the right `this` or allows you to specify which `this` to use these days.

Comment: @Gohn67, both of those question do not give the correct answer, I never use _bindAll and my function always get called with the correct View context applied to 'this'.

Comment: @jax Yeah good point. I don't use `_.bindAll` either. I typically use `_.bind` for certain use cases. I think one case is adding a callback to the collection `add` event. I could be wrong. I didn't answer this question because I'm not sure when to use `bind` most of the time. Usually I don't use it and will only add it when I get a scope bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jax is right that you don't have to manually bind your View methods and events in the latest version of Backbone (Currently 1.1.0). There are earlier versions where this is true too, but I can't remember which ones.

There are cases where you will need to bind your view methods to make them work correctly. These cases are basic Javascript scoping and not related to Backbone JS specifically.

It is best not to use `_.bindAll`. Instead you should bind on a case-by-case basis using `_.bind` if you are using Underscore JS.

Actually if you are using Backbone, you won't need to use `_.bind` either. There are shortcut methods on the Backbone `Events` class. This means you can use these shortcuts in the `Collection` and `Model` classes too since they each have the Events class mixed in essentially.

This what you will need to do in your view class to attach listeners to collections or models.

```
this.collection.on('add', this.appendItem, this);
```

or

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

The third parameter binds the view object scope to the `render` method. Without this, the `render` method will be called with the scope of the model I believe.

On a side note you can also do this:

```
this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem, this);
```

The `on` method is actually an alias to `bind`, but I think it is clearer to use `on`. Using `bind` can be confusing. Looks like the Backbone docs prefer `on` and `off` to `bind` and `unbind`.

Here are two jsFiddles that illustrates what I'm talking. My examples are modified from this tutorial example: http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/5.html

This tutorial has been around for a long time actually, so may not be the best one to use. It does seem like it may have been updated a bit since it does use Backbone 1.10. I will also note that it uses `_.bindAll`.

Version 1 uses binding correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/ChTjs/

Relevant methods here:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new List();
    this.collection.on('add', this.appendItem, this);
    this.collection.on('add', this.updateCount, this);
    this.collection.on('remove', this.updateCount, this);
    this.counter = 0;
    this.render();
},
```

and here:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
this.model.on('remove', this.unrender, this);
```

Here is a jsFiddle version that doesn't bind the view scope to the callbacks. http://jsfiddle.net/LpEW8/1/

Try it out and slowly add in the bindings to get the code working again. I just realized this  is actually mentioned in the Backbone docs. Search `Binding "this"`

**EDIT 2**

Just realized that it would be better to use the `listenTo` method. The advantage here is that you the callback will always be bound to the view/object that call `listenTo`. So no need to pass `this` like when using `on`. The additional benefit is that the listeners will be removed automatically, whereas that is not the case when using `on`

So instead of this:

```
this.collection.on('add', this.appendItem, this);
this.collection.on('add', this.updateCount, this);
this.collection.on('remove', this.updateCount, this);
```

You do this in your view:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.appendItem);
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.updateCount);
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.updateCount);
```

Here is the anchor link to `listenTo` in Backbone docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

Also here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ChTjs/2/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, '**this**' is bound by default to the View for all functions attached to the Backbone View, manually binding is no longer required.