# Render issue in View with subviews in Backbone/Require app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

From a home view I try to render some subviews that should reside in the home view page, for example grades view and its subview grade view, one is visible and fills full page at a time when the navbar icon is clicked. Home page has a navbar with links for showing this subviews one at a time. Home view is like Facebook mobile app page with navbar and subviews like the feed, friend requests etc. populates the page under the navbar.

I have implemented one of the subviews but cannot render it. Homeview successfully renders. Each subview render itself at initialisation and the grades collection fetches itself at initialisation.

homeview:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'ratchet',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',

  'text!home/hometemplate.html',

  'grades/gradesview',

  ],
  function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, HomeTemplate, GradesView){
      var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

          el: $('body'),
          initialize: function() {
              //X-construct the subviews in initialize to create them once.
              this.gradesView = new GradesView();

              this.render();
          },
          template: _.template( HomeTemplate ),
          render: function() {
              this.$el.html( this.template() );
              //X-Place the Subview element into DOM.
              this.$('#gradesviewcontainer').html( this.gradesView.el );
          },

        });

        return HomeView;
})
```

gradesview:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'grades/gradescollection',
    'grades/gradeview',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone, GradesCollection, GradeView){
        var GradesView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#gradescontainer'),
            //model: GradeModel,
            initialize: function(){
                this.collection = new GradesCollection;
                this.collection.each(function(item) {
                  console.log(item);
                });

                this.render();
            },
            //template:,

            render: function() {
                this.collection.each( function (item) {
                    this.renderGrade( item );
                }, this );
            },

            renderGrade: function(item) {
                this.gradeView = new GradeView( {model: item} );
                this.$el.append( this.gradeView.el );
            },
        });

        return GradesView;
})
```

gradescollection:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'grades/grademodel',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone, GradeModel) {
        var GradesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({

            model: GradeModel,
            url: '/grade',
            initialize: function() {
                this.fetch();
            },

        });

    return GradesCollection;
});
```

gradeview:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'grades/grademodel',
    'text!grades/gradetemplate.html'
    ],
    function(_, Backbone, GradeModel, GradeTemplate){
        var GradeView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'div',
            initialize: function(){
                this.render();
            },
            template: _.template( GradeTemplate ),

            render: function() {
                this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ));
                return this;
            },
        });

        return GradeView;
})
```

Another problem here is that the navbar links each an html anchor is not working in homeview render.
In JS Console I can see the resource json responded from my server, an array of objects as intended: `[{"coursename":"Math","gradenumeric":100},{"coursename":"Phys","gradenumeric":80}]`. What is the point I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to remove `el: $('#gradescontainer')` from GradesView. You shouldn't set the `el` element for a subview since you are going to append it to the parent view that is not rendered yet.

I included a ver simplified version that works just by `el: $('#gradescontainer')`. In my example I removed the GradeModel and GradeCollection and just put some placeholder code for simplicity.

This example should render "GRADE TEMPLATE" five times, once for each Grade model. Try putting  `el: $('#gradescontainer')` back into `GradesView` and you will see that "GRADE TEMPLATE" is not longer rendered.

Your other issue was that the collection was calling `fetch` in the initialize method. This uses AJAX so the models will be loaded asynchronously. You need to bind a listener event to the collection when you initialize your GradesView. For example:

```
this.collection.on('add', this.renderGrade, this);
```

---

Example 1: This example does not use Models/Collections. Just illustrates that you need to remove `el: $('#gradescontainer')`

```js
var GradeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  template: "GRADE TEMPLATE",

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    return this;
  },
});


var GradesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.renderGrade({id:i});
    }
  },

  renderGrade: function(item) {
    this.gradeView = new GradeView({model: item});
    this.$el.append(this.gradeView.el);
  },
});

var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $('#test'),
   initialize: function() {
     this.gradesView = new GradesView();
     this.render();
   },
   template: '<h1>GRADES</h1><div id="gradesviewcontainer"></div>',
   render: function() {
     this.$el.html( this.template );
     this.$('#gradesviewcontainer').html( this.gradesView.el );
   },

 });

var v = new HomeView();
```

---

Example 2: This example uses Models/Collections. Models are manually added to the Collection. Fetch is not used for simplicity. This is basically the same as example 1.

```js
var GradeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    letter: 'A'
  }
});

var GradesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
  model: GradeModel,
  url: '/grade'
});

var GradeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  template: _.template("<li><%= letter %></li>"), 
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  },
});


var GradesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection = new GradesCollection();
    this.collection.add(new GradeModel({letter: 'A'}));
    this.collection.add(new GradeModel({letter: 'B'}));
    this.collection.add(new GradeModel({letter: 'C'}));    
    this.collection.add(new GradeModel({letter: 'D'}));
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each( function (item) {
      this.renderGrade( item );
    }, this )
  },

  renderGrade: function(item) {
    this.gradeView = new GradeView({model: item});
    this.$el.append(this.gradeView.el);
  },
});

var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#test'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.gradesView = new GradesView();
    this.render();
  },
  template: '<h1>GRADES</h1><div id="gradesviewcontainer"></div>',
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template );
    this.$('#gradesviewcontainer').html(this.gradesView.el);
  },

});

var v = new HomeView();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: My problem I think wşth rendering  a collection. I should see a real implementation of collection rendering.

Comment: I am trying an ordinary array.

Comment: Yeah, looking at it again there is an issue with your collection since you call `fetch` during initialize. You need to add a listener event since fetch is async.

Comment: You mean I should put a listen to in the grades view initialise. To make it clear, when I create the GradesCollection in GradesView initialize the control does not wait for the GradesCollection to be created but continues to execute next lines, for example this.render(). So before the fetch() of GradesCollection in its initialisation fetches collection, view renders without it. So this means it is async.

Comment: Yes that is correct since fetch makes an AJAX request to your server endpoint to fetch the data. Those requests are asynchronous. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568472/is-bindall-outdated/21572523#21572523

Comment: so I will try with     this.listenTo( this.collection, 'sync', this.render ); and omit the render after it, in GradesView. And use rest as it was.

Comment: Was it same if ı didn't init the grades collection with fetch(), but after creation of it in grades view make a fetch for it, regarding the async issue?

Comment: If you just manually add the Models to collection, then it will not be async. I'm finishing up an example that uses this approach right now. After that I will add an async example.

Comment: thanks very much it now works. renders in DOM. But strangely as I have noted in question the ordinary links does not work and does not lead to the ordinary id portions of the document. I am using ratchet with a navbar that has hash links to ids in the slider and a slider.

Comment: Great. Do you need still need an example for handling the asynchronous fetch?

Comment: The problem is when I click links to the subviews in navbar they update the url as localhost:8080/view1 and refreshing page does not bring the app, nothing renders with this url. One should delete the url hash parts. for an app this is ok but for users from browser this is not desirable. Just today I have switched in my repo branch from Routers version branch of mine to this nested view branch because of this refresh problem. Hoe to overcome this.

Comment: Yeah that's annoying since you'd need to deal with this server-side. Maybe just make all routes on server render your index page. I think the Backbone Router should render the correct page. Been a while since I used the Router so you may need to make some adjustments.

Comment: As an idea defining routes as well for each subview that navigates to home view url. Making them route their respective renders they render alone on the page or don't render at all since dom is destroyed after refresh.

Comment: You should probably ask that as another question since it is a different problem.

Comment: Sorry just skipped your comment "Great. Do you need still need an example for handling the asynchronous fetch?" No my project works now. Thanks very much. exempt the part you pointed I should ask as a new question: the refresh issue with routers.